# How to change docker repository for masakari?

Tags: docker, openstack

hi i am install masakari using kolla-ansible when it try to pull container it throw error `The repository not exist or request denied i check docker hub the image not present there , is there setting in kolla to download the docker image with other name which is present on docker hub.

Global.yml

```
#kolla_base_distro: "centos"

#kolla_install_type: "binary"

#openstack_release: "ussuri"
```

Comment: do you have tired to build the missing masakari docker images with `kolla-build masakari`?

Comment: how can i integrate it with other services then?

Comment: @Tobias i check on docker hub this odivlad/masakari image is present is there any setting in kolla to download this image for masakari ?

Comment: Kolla-ansible requires a consistent style of the docker image names based on the settings in your globals.yml. If you want to use a specific one from docker-hub you could download the image manually with `docker pull` and rename it with `docker tag` command to match the name style, which kolla-anisble requires. When kolla-ansible finds the requested docker image on the local computer, it doesn't try to download it again.

Comment: hi @Tobias "odivlad/masakari" this masakari image is present on docker hub can you please post the answer with step how to rename and integrate it to my other openstack services.Also i update my post with global.yml file can you please elaborate the steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `global.yml` it should work when you run the following commands to download and rename your prefered docker-images:

```
docker pull odivlad/masakari:api
docker pull odivlad/masakari:engine
docker pull odivlad/masakari:rc8

docker tag odivlad/masakari:api kolla/centos-binary-masakari-api:ussuri
docker tag odivlad/masakari:engine kolla/centos-binary-masakari-engine:ussuri
docker tag odivlad/masakari:rc8 kolla/centos-binary-masakari-rc8:ussuri
```

After this the images should match the correct name and should be found by the kolla-ansible run.

I have never used masakari by myself und can not check this in my own kolla-ansible test setup. So it is only a theoretical solution for your problem.

Comment: thank you for this this is the same problem with cloudkitty it is not present on docker but it is present with other names. Can you DM here . Thank you i appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try the cloudkitty service.

Comment: No, sorry. I only used the basic openstack components until now.

Comment: Did you try the above solution for any service is that work ?

Comment: I already used the solution with the renaming with`docker tag`, but only on containers I already build by myself with `kolla-build` on other deployments with a different name. If the solution doesn't fully works for you, then the docker-images from docker hub are not kompatible with kolla or you have still a mismatch in the names compared to your other docker-images.

Comment: can you please update the answer to elaborate how to build the cloudkitty and masakari images , so if the rename not work i use the `kolla-build` solution. please.

Comment: see already my first comment below your question, where I already told it to you

Comment: i check but i never build the image using `kolla-build` so we you just give example to show how to build `masakari` let say.

Comment: see official documentation: https://docs.openstack.org/kolla/latest/admin/image-building.html